# ORACLE char(13) replace in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have an email template which I need to display for edit (if needed) respectively in a form. In the ORACLE DB the email is saved as follows:

```
Hello,' || chr(13) || ' ' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || 'You are now a registered user' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || 'Authorization User Email: @username' || chr(13) || 'Initial Password: @password' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || ' ' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || 'Before you Sign-In, you must change your initial account password.' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || ' ' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || 'Application could be downloaded from here: URL' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || ' ' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || 'Please read the Terms of Use, following the link: URL' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || 'By downloading, installing or using the App, you indicate that you accept these Terms of Use and that you agree to abide by them. Your download, installation or use of the App constitutes your acceptance of the Terms of Use, which takes effect on the date on which you download, install or use the App.' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || ' ' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || 'Regards,' || chr(13) || '' || chr(13) || '
```

How can I represent the text with the new lines so that it is visually okay for the user. (below)

```
Hello,

You are now a registered user.
Authorization User Email: @username
Initial Password: @password

Before you Sign-In, you must change your initial account password.

Application could be downloaded from here: URL

Please read the Terms of Use, following the link: URL
By downloading, installing or using the App, you indicate that you accept these Terms of Use and that you agree to abide by them. Your download, installation or use of the App constitutes your acceptance of the Terms of Use, which takes effect on the date on which you download, install or use the App.

Regards,
app team
```

I tried with Regex but couldn't succeed...
Also once text is edited by user in the View I guess it needs to be saved again with char(13) ... which again don't know how to do...

Comment: Could you share your expected output to illustrate what you mean by "visually okay"?

Comment: @BoyanMihnev  `CHR(13)` **is** the newline character. If you write this to a text file you'll see that the text already splits into multiple lines. *HTML*, not ASP.NET, ignores newlines though. Instead of  a newline you should have used `<br>` for a line break, or paragraph and div tags

Comment: @BoyanMihnev this means the string `CHR(13)` doesn't even exist in the string, so it can't be replaced. How do you display that text? If display it as HTML, you need to replace newlines with line breaks (<br>) or divs. If you display it in a multiline textbox, you shouldn't have to do anything

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `chr(10)` instead of `chr(13)`, or possibly `chr(13)||chr(10)`. Or as Panagiotis Kanavos suggested, if this is an email, use `<br>` instead.

If you have a variable in a query or a PL/SQL program, you can do something like: `v_email := replace(v_email, chr(13), chr(10));`

`chr(13)` is the carriage return character and `chr(10)` is the line feed character. If you've ever used an old typewriter, `chr(13)` is like pushing the bar back so you can type on the left-hand side, and `chr(10)` is like twisting the knob to move the page to the next line. Windows uses `chr(13)||chr(10)` for new lines, which imitates the older typewriters where you had to do two separate movements. Unix uses only `chr(10)` for newlines, which imitates the newer typewriters that automatically moved the page after you pushed the bar across.

Yes, even in 2021 we still have to occasionally think like typewriters because different systems imitate them. For example, on some old Windows and DOS programs, only using `chr(13)` will mean the characters will overwrite each other and your text will be cutoff. Some programs will just ignore a single `chr(13)`, and some will treat them like generic whitespace. The `chr(13)` is usually unnecessary, but you almost certainly need a `chr(10)`.

If you add more information about your application, database program, or email client, we could give more specific advice for how to fix this issue.